# Трекинг пользователей мобильного приложения

Tags: android, ios

Можно ли узнать в мобильном приложении источник (рекламный канал), с которого пользователь совершил установку, чтобы выдать ему определенную подборку и функционала?

Comment: Можно. По идее лицокнижный deeplink вам должен подойти